# How to Solve the Integral $B''(x) / B'(x) = -(a + b)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

A step of a particular differential equations question I am working on involves the following step: $B''(x) / B'(x) = -(a + b)$

I know that I am supposed to integrate both sides, but I do not understand the result:

$ \ln (B'(x)) = -(a + b)x + \ln(C)$

Why is it $ln(C)$ rather than just $C$?

After this step, simplification leads to:

$ B'(x) = Ce^{-(a + b)x}$

I also do not understand why C is now multiplied by the exponential, rather than added to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The constant term is written as $\ln(C)$ rather than merely $C$ to make the form of the answer more convenient.

If one had used $C$, then the form of the answer would have been

$$ B^\prime=e^Ce^{-(a+b)x} $$

But then, $e^C$ is just some arbitrary positive constant.

By choosing a constant in the form $\ln(C)$ instead of simply $C$, the constant is $e^{\ln(C)}=C$ which puts the result in a simpler form.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$y'(x)=v(x)$$and we get
$$\int\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{v(x)}dx=\int-a-bdx$$

Answer (score 0):

I get $\ln(B'(x))=-(a+b)x+C \implies B'(x)=e^{-(a+b)x+C}\implies B'(x)=e^C\cdot e^{-(a+b)x}\implies B'(x)=Ce^{-(a+b)x}$.

Note that $e^C$ is just a constant (which can be represented by $C$ again,  though technically it's a different constant).